# Oh no, my library!

Tags: knowledge, pattern, english, literature

In my study I have a great collection of books of fine literature and pop fiction alike. Looks like Posling the Poltergeist has broken into my study and pulled another one of his practical "jokes".

It appears that Posling has scrambled up all of the letters and characters in my books!  Some are only mildly scrambled, and others are much worse.

Fortunately, the scramblings were only done sentence by sentence.  Listed below are the opening sentences for various books.

Can you help me reconstruct each of the sentences and identify the books?

**Book 1:**

> allC me Ismhae.l

**Book 2:**

> I twsa  abright cl odad iyAn prli, dnat  ehclco swekre rtsiikg nthtrinee.

**Book 3:**

> nIa  hl oiheteng  rodnu th erlieaevd o hbib.t

**Book 4:**

> oyf u eIrlly a awtt nroahe atobiu  t,thieft  strh gyi' nuollbprlo ay bnatwoktn owis  wrhe e I warnbso,ad  wnatm oyh lu slcyihohd aosw dlike,a ndh mow ya epns rewtercc uoi pndeda abl lferoetyhha ed me a,danl   tlht Davaid opCpreefdkli do irnf pact ,bud oIt' enfe k llie igiogn ntio  i ,fty uownao tk o nwtehtr ut.th

**Book 5:**

> Ma. rMn.rdr sus  Delo,fnyburuf em,o rPirv eDev tri eweurr, poot sdhayt att h eye erwe pfetrcnyoarl m,kt lao vnheyu rum.y ch

**Book 6:**

> ts Ip we aasa luoberut .nr

**Book 7:**

> F raoiut n then uhcadrte bacwkrsaeto f tehnuf ahbosnailend  fhoee t sew etrpsrln imaar oef th Gaaxlylsia em s alulngr erda dleyeswl uo.n

**Book 8:**

> sa Iw tebto shefi ,m tiewtts tesah   wsto ofrsteatmi  wt ,isae heg  fo iwsd ,omtws a egtifhef oo hlaosis i ,aewntetss e chpfo o l hbfe ieta ih,eewcts ophf  indu rco iwyl atei,te sats hosenof  ,Lgiiht  tweaths sea s foo nasDnes rks,ahti wrstep iog  noph ,wt ifashet  tenw eor s idaf,rw e hpedeate irvyhi enegfbo ,su e  ardtniwgohh enbrfews o,ee ur we iol rga gnldc taoeien t,  veeHwreew aollg ignreidt  eto ctwhe anhy r -i str,h thoeiepro w ssdf  or alatie ekp htenersp ,redthoa osi oem t sft ioissieant uioiertthiess ntsd no isit ebnrigeic,dv eegf or  ordooofrvei il  t,n eh respuadliteo vegfer  eorcmsa iloynopn.

**Book 9:**

> fmaegpl,tactl ,Smpn  rBuirc  l uamltok obMhaw yn utarhieieet foa  drhm ailrse  nho lgaray.on or esoabrh crr a cldewzidaas

---

**Clarifications:**

- Each sentence is the first sentence of a book. The amount of each letter/character in each scrambled sentence is the same as in the original sentence (unless I made a mistake -- nevertheless, it should be close).
- Each book can be done as an independent puzzle. Try as many as you can -- even if you can only figure out one book, you are still encouraged to post an answer.
- Computer/programming aid *might* be helpful, but I think all of these are doable by a clever person
- Post the unscrambled sentence *and* the corresponding book title for each book you solve.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whew! Your books are:

1.

> Moby Dick (*Call me Ishmael*)

2.

> 1984 (*It was a bright cold day in April, and the clocks were striking thirteen.*)

3.

> The Hobbit (*In a hole in the ground there lived a hobbit.*)

4.

> Catcher in the Rye (*If you really want to hear about it, the first thing you’ll probably want to know is where I was born, and what my lousy childhood was like, and how my parents were occupied and all before they had me, and all that David Copperfield kind of crap, but I don’t feel like going into it, if you want to know the truth.*)

5.

> Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's (or Philosopher's) Stone (*Mr. and Mrs. Dursley, of number four, Privet Drive, were proud to say that they were perfectly normal, thank you very much.*)

6.

> Fahrenheit 451 (*It was a pleasure to burn*)

7.

> Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy (*Far out in the uncharted backwaters of the unfashionable end of the western spiral arm of the Galaxy lies a small unregarded yellow sun.*) — thanks @ffao

8.

> A Tale of Two Cities (*It was the best of times, it was the worst of times, it was the age of wisdom, it was the age of foolishness, it was the epoch of belief, it was the epoch of incredulity, it was the season of Light, it was the season of Darkness, it was the spring of hope, it was the winter of despair.*)

9.

> Ulysses (*Stately, plump Buck Mulligan came from the stairhead, bearing a bowl of lather on which a mirror and a razor lay crossed.*)

Comment: Can you also post the unscrambled sentences? Thanks.  Also, recheck (4).

Comment: I would check your answer for number four. You have only guessed two of the words in it, not the name of the book.

Comment: @scholtes and paste - yeah that's on hold for the moment

Comment: @scholtes OK, changed - I'm doing all this visually at the moment - there's a zero percent chance I'll get all these without some kind of assistance.

Comment: @question_asker That's no excuse for getting my favorite book from my teenage years wrong ;)

Comment: @paste haha I *haaaaated* that book, but probably mostly because it felt more like an obligation than a pleasure

Comment: @question_asker Yeah, _having_ to read books just makes them less enjoyable. I read it on my own though, so that probably helped.

Comment: @question_asker I've got to say, I am impressed that someone got all of these.  And to top it off, so quickly!

I'm curious: what was (were) your general strategy (strategies)? What was the hardest part of the puzzle?

Comment: @scholtes I'll never reveal my secrets! OK well basically it was a combination of eyeballing and then checking hunches. Also, the capital letters gave me a headstart on some of them.

Answer (score 3):

Book 2:

> 1984: It was a bright cold day in April, and the clocks were striking thirteen.